# Where does VBA Debug.Print log to?

Tags: vba, debugging, ms-office

Where does `Debug.Print` output messages?

Comment: [specific to the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Language Reference for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278865(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-debug-print/

Answer (score 413, accepted):

Where do you want to see the output?

Messages being output via `Debug.Print` will be displayed in the immediate window which you can open by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

You can also *Activate* the so called **Immediate Window** by clicking View -> Immediate Window on the VBE toolbar

[image]

Comment: This is true if you are in an office application which supports VBA, but if you are using via WSH you may need to use MsgBox (*shudder*) or some similar technique as the immediate window is not available.

Answer (score 109):

`Debug.Print` outputs to the "Immediate" window.

[image: Debug.Print outputs to the Immediate window]

Also, you can simply type `?` and then a statement directly into the immediate window (and then press Enter) and have the output appear right below, like this:

[image: simply type ? and then a statement directly into the immediate window]

This can be very handy to quickly output the property of an object...

`? myWidget.name`

...to *set* the property of an object...

`myWidget.name = "thingy"`

...or to even execute a function or line of code, while in debugging mode:

`Sheet1.MyFunction()`