# Open files with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

In a folder I have different Excel Workbooks like this:

```
Exercise1
Exercise2
Exercise3
...
ExerciseN
```

I want to open all files (all .xls) in the folder in the same Excel workbook on different sheets.

I suppose it would be something like this, but not:

```
Sub Macro1()
    For i = 1 To ?? 
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Exercisei.xls"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Each Exercise is an xls workbook with one sheet?

Comment: Examples of how to list and loop through all files of a given type in a specified folder here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017318/vba-getting-list-of-all-files-with-esy-extension-in-a-directory

Comment: did you want to copy these worksheets from opened workbooks to the source workbook? You can't just open 2 separate workbooks as 1 workbook - you either copy the spreadsheets or open as 2 separate workbooks. hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is a simple sub routine to open all excel files in a defined folder. You can adjust your file names in variable. I have simplified the macro defined here [Files in a Directory](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/files-in-a-directory.html)

```
Sub openfiles()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "c:\test\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??") '<-- you can use * and ? wild cards here.
    Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    fileName = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: as far as i can see this only opens workbooks and I think the OP probably wants to not only open the workbooks but copy-paste all the sheets from those opened workbooks to the source workbook.

Comment: @vba4all thanks for pointing out. I just read the post again, I think you are right, that was an interesting way to identify the problem :)

Comment: btw the link that I gave includes getting worksheet names from the opened documents. If he wants he can tune that code to copy sheets to his original file. I guess.

Comment: you also forgot to include `Dir` within the cycle to go through all of them anyway...

Comment: @Raugmor thanks for the feedback. I have updated the code accordingly. Now it is working fine for me. As I mentioned in the post this is a very basic way, may not be the best way to do it.

Comment: [link](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder)  Use this code as your base to loop through folders, then edit the action each time it opens the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

This example is for **2** .xls files:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim master As Workbook, awb As Workbook
    Dim N As Long
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, i As Long
    N = 2
    Set master = ThisWorkbook
    s1 = "C:\TestFolder\Examplez.xls"

    For i = 1 To N
        s2 = Replace(s1, "z", CStr(i))
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=s2
        Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveSheet.Copy after:=master.Sheets(master.Sheets.Count)
        awb.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Each worksheet is copied to the master workbook and then that Example.xls is closed.
You would change the folder name and adjust the number of files to process.