# Recognize which Excel pivot tables will overlap after refresh

Tags: excel, pivot, overlap, cube, overlapping

Within extensive Excel files (=approx. 40 sheets) there are many pivots (drawn from a single OLAP cube; hence one connection for all pivots). Often, there are several pivot tables within the same worksheet.

Whenever there were changes to the OLAP cube, it might take a long time to find out which of those cause an overlap and hence lead to a cancellation of a refresh. **Is there a way to find out which out of many pivot tables leads to an overlap when refreshing the connection?**

**Side conditions:** holding each pivot table in a separate sheet is not an option (to many sheets), converting the data to cube functions neither.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unless you know something about the structure of the Pivots beforehand.  That is, a Pivot grouped by Month cannot have more than 12 columns.  The overlapping ones are probably not limited like that though.  Excel encourages you to put PivotTables on their own Worksheets to ensure no overlap.  How many sheets would it be?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the ranges in VBA with the following:

```
Activesheet.pivottables(1).databodyrange.address
```

You can also use the Intersect function to determine if two ranges intersect.

http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=154:referencing-an-excel-pivot-table-range-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475

You will have to dig further to see if it is possible to move a pivot table using VBA. Alternatively, you could use the macro recorder to recreate the pivot tables on the fly and position them based on the boundaries of the pivot created on the same page before it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves some VBA, but can be a copy/paste:

https://exceleratorbi.com.au/find-overlapping-pivot-tables/

Essentially it involves "logging" each refresh of a pivot**. When your pivot fails the entry won't be logged. Allowing you to identify the failed table.

**You will need to get the list/order of pivots from a successful run first

*Alternatively*

You could get a list of all the tables, and their sheets, then make a guess at what is overlapping:

https://excelreality.blogspot.nl/2014/08/finding-source-pivot-table-cannot.html

*Alternatively*

The following answer suited my need with a minor adjustment (removed the update due to memory error), Then read the last table before the error:
    https://superuser.com/questions/703847/how-do-i-find-which-pivot-tables-has-an-error-in-excel-2010

as

```
Sub ref()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet, Pivot As PivotTable, result As Boolean
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
        Debug.Print Sheet.name & "-->" & Pivot.name
        Pivot.RefreshTable
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

View output in immediate window:

[Where does VBA Debug.Print log to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916287/where-does-vba-debug-print-log-to)