# Looping INDEX-MATCH VBA with Sub or Function not defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a looping INDEX-MATCH VBA that I am trying to debug, as it is constantly throwing a Sub or Function not defined error. With what I have already found on this site, I was able to check my references, but I still seem to be missing something ("Solver" is checked). At this point, an extra pair of eyes would be most helpful!

```
Private Sub Looping_Index_Match()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell as range
Dim IndexRange as range
Dim MatchRange as range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D42:D241")

 With  Workbook("WorkCenter.xlsm").Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)
     Set IndexRange=Range(.Range("M2"),.Range(“M2”).end(xlup))
     Set MatchRange= Range(.Range("L2"),.Range(“L2”).end(xlup))
 End With

For Each cell In rng
    Cell.Offset(0,1)=Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(IndexRange,Application.WorksheetFuntion.Match(cell,Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell,MatchRange,0))
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating=True
End Sub
```

Notes: There are two workbooks involved. Data from the "Work Center" workbook column M is being retrieved and entered into the "Summary" workbook, as matched by serial numbers found in column L.

Comment: Use `option Explicit` at the top of this module, if there is a typo, this will alert you before runtime.  `ComboBox1` may not be in scope? Otherwise, please indicate which line raises the error.

Comment: Apologies, it's late in the day here. The error highlights the name of the sub itself in yellow, and "Workbook" - which I am guessing is where the code stops working.

I've never used option `option Explicit` before -  can you elaborate?

Comment: No worries, sometimes you just need another set of eyes. Was it the issue with `ComboBox1`?

Comment: See above. This code is part of a series of subs that run from a `Userform`.

Comment: Unless this code is in the user form module, then combobox1 is orut of scope. Qualify it to its parent form per the answer below :)

Comment: The collection is `Workbooks`, not `Workbook`.

Comment: Discussed a similar issue yesterday: [How to fix run time error 424 when accessing the value of a CheckBox in Excel VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557232/how-to-fix-run-time-error-424-when-accessing-the-value-of-a-checkbox-in-excel-vb)

Comment: @Comintern - Yep, it was just the s that hamstrung me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim yoursheet As Worksheet
Dim yourworkbook As Workbook


Set yourworkbook = Workbooks("Book3.xlsx")
Set yoursheet = yourworkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)


With yoursheet
Set IndexRange = Range(.Range("M2"), .Range("M2").End(xlDown))
Set MatchRange = Range(.Range("L2"), .Range("L2").End(xlDown))

End With



ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("e42").Formula = "=index([" & yourworkbook.Name & "]" & yoursheet.Name & "!" & IndexRange.Address & ",match(d42" & ",[" & yourworkbook.Name & "]" & yoursheet.Name & "!" & MatchRange.Address & ",0))"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("e42:e241").FillDown

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("e42:e241").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("e42:e241").PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Unload UserForm1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.AddItem "Sheet2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

i will share a quick example i built:
i made a simple userform with 1 combobox and one command button. to the combobox i only added the name of the first sheet. the command button calls another macro stored in a separate module call Looping_Index, passing the combobox value

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Looping_Index(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.AddItem "Sheet1"
End Sub

Sub Looping_Index(hoja As String)

Sheets(hoja).Activate
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

this a simple example on how to work with userforms and passing values. hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. However, this code is in the user form module. 

Now that I've added an "s" to the end of `Workbook` (*facepalm*), the next error to debug is this: "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class".

The code involved:

`cell.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(IndexRange, Application.WorksheetFuntion.Match(cell, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell, MatchRange, 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

This code below is working for me(same module):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim yoursheet As Worksheet
Set yoursheet = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)


With yoursheet
Set IndexRange = Range(.Range("M2"), .Range("M2").End(xlDown))
Set MatchRange = Range(.Range("L2"), .Range("L2").End(xlDown))

End With



ActiveSheet.Range("e42").Formula = "=index(" & yoursheet.Name & "!" & IndexRange.Address & ",match(d42" & "," & yoursheet.Name & "!" & MatchRange.Address & ",0))"
ActiveSheet.Range("e42:e241").FillDown

Unload UserForm1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.AddItem "Sheet2"
End Sub
```

Comment: That is very close! How are you accounting for the name of the `Workbook` where the `Sheets` are located?