# In the Outlook object model is there a way to see which "view" outlook is in?

Tags: vba, outlook, office-interop

How can what category of items Outlook is showing as indicated by the highlighted icon shown at the bottom left of the window, in the case of of image below it is email. I want a method that works regardless of which folder or calendar is selected as user might have multiple. The closest I have got so far is to examine
`Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` and check the `DefaultMessageClass` property.

Is there a more direct way of determining what the user has selected in the icon menu show below?

[image: here]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227329/4539709

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub NavigationPaneModuleName()

    Dim objPane As NavigationPane
    Dim objModule As Object

    ' Get the current NavigationPane object.
    Set objPane = ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane

    Debug.Print objPane.CurrentModule.Name

EndRoutine:
    Set objModule = Nothing
    Set objPane = Nothing

End Sub
```