# Move all highlighted emails, not just the active one - and a question about terminology - VBA Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that reads the subject line of an email, finds the UID and copies it to the clipboard. I then search Outlook for the UID and highlight certain emails. I want to send them all to a folder.

I have the loop and move worked out, but it only moves the active/selected email. How do I have move all of the highlighted emails and not just the selected email?

```vb
Select Case Outlook.Application.ActiveWindow.Class
    Case olInspector
        Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Case olExplorer
        Set myItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
End Select

myItem.Move objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(strSubFolder1)
```

I'm using the terms "active" and "selected" interchangeably which may be inaccurate. By active or selected I mean the email that is being displayed in the reading pane.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227329/4539709

Answer (score 0):

`.Item(1)` means you only work with one item - try moving each item in the `Selection` instead

```vb
Dim objNS As NameSpace, itm, sel As Object, i As Long
Dim dest As Folder

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set dest = objNS.Folders(1).Folders("Test")

Select Case Outlook.Application.ActiveWindow.Class
    Case olInspector
        ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Move dest
    Case olExplorer
        Set sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        For i = sel.Count To 1 Step -1
            sel(i).Move objNS.Folders(1).Folders("Test")
        Next i
End Select
```

Comment: Move will change the collection you are iterating over. It is better to use a down loop from Count to 1 step-1