# Automate number entry in cells based on condition in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have entries in columns as follows:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
1      0     0      1    0
```

As you see, 1 repeats at every 3rd position after "1 in Col1". I want to write a code that if I type "4" then 1 should repeat at every 4th position...and if I write 2 then it should repeat at every 2nd position...

Example output: I type in a cell: "4"

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
1      0     0      0    1
```

Note: I dont know how to create tables in StackOverflow, any help there would be great too :(

Thanks!!

Comment: How long is it supposed to go for?

Answer (score 2):

put this in A1 and drag/copy over:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1,$A$3)=0,1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is some example of a `Sub` with "optional parameters":

```
Public Sub RepeatMe(Optional repeatEach As Long = 3, Optional repeatLen As Long = 20)

    Dim myCell  As Range
    Cells.Clear

    Dim cnt As Long
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, repeatLen)).Value = 0

    For cnt = 1 To repeatLen Step repeatEach
        Cells(1, cnt) = 1
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

To run it, [go to the immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916287/where-does-vba-debug-print-log-to), write `RepeatMe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Shouldn't `repeatEach` be initialized to 4?

Comment: Nevermind my first comment... I see how the OP wants a dynamic approach.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I am usually ignoring the `0` by default. :)