# MS Access database - ('" & CUSIPS & "') in Where condition

Tags: ms-access

Just I want to check what is exactly ('" & CUSIPS & "') in where condition or criteria...

Could you please help on this. Thank you

Regards,
Jagannath

Comment: Quite difficult with no info at all ...

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your Query Editor, you can add `[CUSIPS]` as a new field to your query. The value will be displayed in this new field.

If you're calling this from VBA, you can use `Debug.Print` just before your query code:

```
Debug.Print CUSIPS
```

See this related question on using `Debug.Print`
[Where does VBA Debug.Print log to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916287/where-does-vba-debug-print-log-to)