# Find / replace text in embedded word object code stopped working

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I have used this code successfully to replace content in an embedded word object from excel. I copied the code for a new excel file but now it doesn't work. It opens the file but doesn't replace although I can see that it IS finding the right text and replacement text. I'm kind of lost as to what is happening.

```
 Dim strFindText As Range
  Dim strReplaceText As Range
  Dim nSplitItem As Long
  
 Set strFindText = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Utilisation Form").Range("c11:c20")
Set strReplaceText = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Utilisation Form").Range("a11:a20")
  nSplitItem = strFindText.Count
Debug.Print strFindText.Item(0)

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Utilisation Form").Shapes
If sh.Name <> "Object 1" Then sh.Delete
Next


Set urobj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Utilisation Form").OLEObjects("Object 1")
Set wordtemp = urobj.Duplicate

wordtemp.Verb Verb:=xlOpen

Set wordtemp2 = wordtemp.Object


For x = 1 To nSplitItem
With wordtemp2.Content.Find
.Forward = True
.Text = strFindText.Item(x)
.ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText.Item(x)
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Next x

End Sub
```

Thanks for the support

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code by running it under the debugger? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @jonsson - yes, i have activated the reference to the word object library...

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - i debug.print the find and replace statements and it seems to be working (in terms of correctly finding the text). I also ran a boolean with msgbox to see if it would trigger in case of a false outcome but no msg box appeared

Comment: Don't use message boxes for checking results in the code. I'd suggest using [Debug.Print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916287/where-does-vba-debug-print-log-to) instead.

Comment: @jonsson I looked again and realized that you were right about the Word Object library. It had been disactivated after I activated it! Found out via checking the wdReplaceAll. Thanks so much both!

Answer (score 0):

When the early-binding technology is used in the code you need to add a corresponding COM reference to be able to use data types. Otherwise, you need to declare everything from the Word object model as `Object` in the code and use the late-binding technology.

To use early binding on an object, you need to know what its v-table looks like. In `Visual Basic`, you can do this by adding a reference to a type library that describes the object, its interface (v-table), and all the functions that can be called on the object. Once that is done, you can declare an object as being a certain type, then set and use that object using the v-table. For example, if you wanted to Automate Microsoft Office Excel using early binding, you would add a reference to the `Microsoft Excel X.0 Object Library` from the `Project`|`References` dialog, and then declare your variable as being of the type `Excel.Application`. From then on, all calls made to your object variable would be early bound.

Read more about that in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) article.